# queue in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, queue, dispatch

how I can run my code one piece at a time. That is, I have a code that you want to perform consistently. Example:

```
- (IBAction)downloadPressed:(id)sender {
    //1
    CGRect frameDelete = deleteButton.frame;
    frameDelete.origin.y = (deleteButton.frame.origin.y-50);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    deleteButton.frame = frameDelete;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [progressLine setProgress:0];

    //2 Wait until the code is executed above, and then run the code below      
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://intercreate.ru/all.zip"];
    [self downloadDataAtURL:fileURL];

    //3 Wait until the code is executed above, and then run the code below
    CGRect frameDelete1 = deleteButton.frame;
    frameDelete1.origin.y = (deleteButton.frame.origin.y+50);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    deleteButton.frame = frameDelete1;  

}
```

That is, I want my code was divided into three parts:

1. the first move the knob up
2. download the file
3. falls back button.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to do things like this is protocol/delegate design pattern. This is, however, obsolete because of blocks. They are the easiest way to accomplish this. They are, for example built in to the excellent [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). You can accomplish what you want with this:

```
- (IBAction)downloadPressed:(id)sender {
CGRect frameDelete = deleteButton.frame;
frameDelete.origin.y = (deleteButton.frame.origin.y-50);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
deleteButton.frame = frameDelete;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[progressLine setProgress:0];

MBProgressHUD *aHud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[aHud showHudAnimated: NO whileExecutingBlock:^
 {
//2 Wait until the code is executed above, and then run the code below      
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://intercreate.ru/all.zip"];
[self downloadDataAtURL:fileURL];
 } completionBlock: ^
  {
//3 Wait until the code is executed above, and then run the code below
CGRect frameDelete1 = deleteButton.frame;
frameDelete1.origin.y = (deleteButton.frame.origin.y+50);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
deleteButton.frame = frameDelete1;  
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}];
}

Progress HUD can do much more, e.g. Show progress indicators :)

Check out this post for blocks usage: [link](http://felixcocoa.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/practical-guide-to-blocks-overuse/)

Answer (score 1):

The first half can been down with the newer block based animations, you can supply a piece of code that is executed when the animation is complete. The second part I would definitely do using notifications, you can post a notification when the file is finished downloading and then any other parts of you code can respond to this event any way they want, change the GUI, notify the user, remove of a list of stuff to down load, you can also add new things to listen to this notification without the original code needing to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the old style `beginAnimations` `commitAnimations` methods.

If you move to the new block based animation methods you get the advantage of being able to use completion handler blocks, and if you use the asynchronous URL downloading methods, the API also provides a place to add completion blocks.

So, essentially:

1. Create an Block based animation to move the button
2. In the completion handler of this animation trigger an asynchronous download
3. In the completion handler of the download fire an animation to move the button.

Because these are all in one block based method (the original animation block) the individual actions will happen one after the other.